# How to call Stored Procedure that consists of Service Broker

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6, service-broker

I don't know if this question duplicate. Please give me the link of it if this question is duplicated.

My question is how to call 2 stored procedures that consists of `BEGIN TRANSACTION & COMMIT TRANSACTION` (Service Broker).

I have 2 stored procedures that use to do some action of Service Broker.

This is the stored procedure that contains `BEGIN CONVERSATION`:

```
USE [EventCloud]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SendingMessage_Group_Id]
    @reference_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ch UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    DECLARE @conversation_group_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    DECLARE @msg NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @conversation_group_id = @reference_id

    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

            BEGIN DIALOG CONVERSATION @ch
                FROM SERVICE [InitiatorService]
                TO SERVICE 'TargetService'
                ON CONTRACT [http://ssb.csharp.at/SSB_Book/c03/HelloWorldContract]
                WITH RELATED_CONVERSATION_GROUP = @conversation_group_id,
                    ENCRYPTION = OFF

            SET @msg = '<HelloWorldRequest>1234</HelloWorldRequest>'

            ;SEND ON CONVERSATION @ch MESSAGE TYPE [http://ssb.csharp.at/SSB_Book/c03/RequestMessage]
            (
                @msg
            )

        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END CATCH
END
```

Code below is an internal activation stored procedure of TargetQueue:

```
USE [EventCloud]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcessRequestMessage]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ch UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    DECLARE @messagetypename NVARCHAR(256)
    DECLARE @messagebody XML
    DECLARE @responsemessage XML;
    DECLARE @errorcode INT
    DECLARE @errormessage NVARCHAR(3000);

    WHILE (1 = 1)
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRANSACTION;
                WAITFOR(
                    RECEIVE TOP (1)
                        @ch = conversation_handle,
                        @messagetypename = message_type_name,
                        @messagebody = CAST(message_body AS XML)
                    FROM TargetQueue
                )

                IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
                BEGIN
                    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
                    BREAK
                END

                -- Process the requested message and send back to Initiator
                ELSE IF (@messagetypename = 'http://ssb.csharp.at/SSB_Book/c03/RequestMessage')
                BEGIN
                    -- Store the received request message in a table
                    INSERT INTO ProcessedMessages (ID, MessageBody, ServiceName, ProcessedDateTime)
                    VALUES (NEWID(), @messagebody, 'TargetService', GETDATE())

                    -- Construct the response message
                    SET @responsemessage =
                        '<HelloWorldResponse>' +
                            @messagebody.value('/HelloWorldRequest[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') +
                        '</HelloWorldResponse>';

                    -- Send the response message back to the initiating service
                    SEND ON CONVERSATION @ch MESSAGE TYPE [http://ssb.csharp.at/SSB_Book/c03/ResponseMessage]
                    (
                        @responsemessage
                    );

                    -- END the conversation on the target's side
                    END CONVERSATION @ch;
                END

                -- End the conversation if meet the message type
                IF (@messagetypename = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/EndDialog')
                BEGIN
                    -- End the conversation
                    END CONVERSATION @ch;
                END

            COMMIT TRANSACTION
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
            PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
        END CATCH
    END
END
```

And this code is used to receive the response message from InitiatorQueue:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcessMessageWithTimeOut]
    @reference_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @receive_timeout INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ch UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    DECLARE @conversation_group_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    DECLARE @messagetypename NVARCHAR(256)
    DECLARE @messagebody XML
    DECLARE @responsemessage XML
    DECLARE @errorcode INT
    DECLARE @errormessage NVARCHAR(3000)
    DECLARE @queuing_order BIGINT
    DECLARE @timeout INT

    SET @conversation_group_id = @reference_id
    SET @timeout = @receive_timeout

    DECLARE @tableMessage TABLE
    (
        queuing_order BIGINT,
        conversation_handle UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
        message_type_name NVARCHAR(256),
        message_body VARBINARY(MAX)
    )

    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
            WAITFOR(
                RECEIVE
                    queuing_order,
                    conversation_handle,
                    message_type_name,
                    message_body
                FROM InitiatorQueue INTO @tableMessage
                WHERE conversation_group_id = @conversation_group_id
            ), TIMEOUT @timeout;

            DECLARE @count INT
            SET @count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @tableMessage)
            IF (@count = 0)
            BEGIN;
                THROW 50001, 'No message response within 5 seconds.', 1
            END

            IF (@count <>2)
            BEGIN
                DECLARE @timeout2 INT
                SET @timeout2 = ABS(@timeout * 0.5)

                WAITFOR(
                    RECEIVE
                        queuing_order,
                        conversation_handle,
                        message_type_name,
                        message_body
                    FROM InitiatorQueue INTO @tableMessage
                    WHERE conversation_group_id = @conversation_group_id
                ), TIMEOUT 5000
                SET @count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @tableMessage)
                IF (@count <> 2)
                BEGIN;
                    THROW 50002, 'End Dialog without Response Message', 1
                END
            END

            WHILE (@count <> 0)
            BEGIN
            SET @queuing_order = (SELECT TOP 1 queuing_order FROM @tableMessage)
            SET @ch = (SELECT conversation_handle FROM @tableMessage WHERE queuing_order = @queuing_order)
            SET @messagetypename = (SELECT message_type_name FROM @tableMessage WHERE queuing_order = @queuing_order)
            SET @messagebody = CAST((SELECT message_body FROM @tableMessage WHERE queuing_order = @queuing_order) AS XML)

                IF (@messagetypename = 'http://ssb.csharp.at/SSB_Book/c03/ResponseMessage')
                BEGIN
                    -- Store the received response message in a table
                    INSERT INTO ProcessedMessages (ID, MessageBody, ServiceName, ProcessedDateTime)
                    VALUES (NEWID(), @messagebody, 'InitiatorService', GETDATE())
                END

                ELSE IF (@messagetypename = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/EndDialog')
                BEGIN
                    -- End the conversation on the initiator's side
                    END CONVERSATION @ch
                END
                DELETE FROM @tableMessage WHERE queuing_order = @queuing_order
                SET @count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @tableMessage)
            END

        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF ERROR_NUMBER() = 50001
        BEGIN
            ;THROW
        END

        IF ERROR_NUMBER() = 50002
        BEGIN
            ;THROW
        END
        ;THROW
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH
END
```

This is my C# code that is used to call the stored procedure:

```
public async Task<TestObject> Begin_Conversation_With_Group_Id(Guid ch)
{
    try
    {
        return await Context.Database.SqlQuery<TestObject>(
        "EXEC SendingMessage_Group_Id @ch",
        new SqlParameter("ch", ch))
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        TestObject exception = new TestObject();
        exception.Data = "Cannot get the data due to: " + " " + e.Message;
        return exception;
    }
}

public async Task<TestObject> Process_Response_Message_With_TimeOut(Guid ch)
{
    var timeout = 5000;
    try
    {
        return await Context.Database.SqlQuery<TestObject>(
            "EXEC ProcessMessageWithTimeOut @ch, @timeout",
            new SqlParameter("ch", ch),
            new SqlParameter("timeout", timeout))
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        TestObject exception = new TestObject();
        exception.Data = "Process is not finish yet due to: " + ex.Message + " " + ex.Number;
        return exception;
    }
}
```

The problem is when I run the code, the message is still in `TargetQueue`, by right it should be received and processed by the internal activation.

But it's working fine if only call 1 stored procedure (`SendingMessage_Group_Id`). The message is able to response back to `InitiatorQueue` instead of staying in `TargetQueue`.

From my guessing, is because of the transaction is not commit yet.

Comment: The C# is nothing to do with that issue. Try to make it working without any C# code by manually executing these procedures.

Comment: It's working fine without C#, which means when I executed it on MSSQL

Comment: Where is supposed to be no difference when you execute code via SSMS or C#. If you have difference, then something is not executed in the same way. Try to use SQL profiler to check what queries are executed when you use C# code and see the difference

Comment: From my guessing is because of the transaction is not commit yet even there is a COMMIT TRANSACTION in the stored procedure.

Comment: you can always validate that by adding some more statements there. For example insert into some table some values. If you are right, then the values will not be inserted

Comment: btw, check the sql server logs. When dealing with service broker these logs are very helpful

Comment: I've checked the SQL profiler, and there is 1 .Net SqlClient Data Provider under Application column.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156896/discussion-between-dmitrij-kultasev-and-kenny-eng).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been solved.

The reason of this issue happened is because I use a framework that cause this situation happened.
The framework is included a transaction at starting, so what I need to do is disable the transaction of the framework then the issue is solved.

The framework that I'm using is [ASP.NET Zero](https://aspnetzero.com/)